# Can I use an if statement to change the API options of the Swiper javascript slider?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm using the Swiper javascript slider, developed by iDangerous. It comes with an initialization  field that I have in my HTML file, in it are the initialization options for the slider.

I'm in a situation where I need to search the webpage for a certain element called `#editor-content`. If the element is found, I need the `simulateTouch` option of the Swiper initialization to be set to `false.` If the element is not found, the `stimulateTouch` option should be set to `true.`

I am using jQuery to accomplish the finding-the-element. I'm using `if(($('#editor-content').length)){...}` to accomplish this. This part works just fine.

Here is what the Swiper initialization  looks like...

```
<script>
swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
spaceBetween: 30,
centeredSlides: true,

// This is the option that needs to be set to true/false depending on whether the #editor-content element exists in the webpage or not...
stimulateTouch = false;***

autoplay: {
delay: 2500,
disableOnInteraction: true,
},
pagination: {
el: '.swiper-pagination',
clickable: true,
},
navigation: {
nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
});
</script>
```

So far, I've tried to initialize the slider differently based on outcome. If it finds the element, initialize the swiper with the option disabled. If it doesn't, initialize the swiper with the option enabled. That didn't work (see code below--and I'm very sorry for the indentation mess):

```
<script>
var swiper = undefined;
function initSwiper() {

// If the jQuery detects an #editor-content element (meaning you're in the editor...)
if((jQuery('#editor-content').length)){

swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
spaceBetween: 30,
centeredSlides: true,

// Element found, so initialize the slider with option below set to false
simulateTouch = false,

autoplay: {
delay: 2500,
disableOnInteraction: true,
},
pagination: {
el: '.swiper-pagination',
clickable: true,
},
navigation: {
nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
});

} else {

var swiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
spaceBetween: 30,
centeredSlides: true,

// Element not found, so initialize the slider with option below set to true
simulateTouch = true,

autoplay: {
delay: 2500,
disableOnInteraction: true,
},
pagination: {
el: '.swiper-pagination',
clickable: true,
},
navigation: {
nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
});

}

}
// Initialize the function      
initSwiper();
</script>
```

I'm expecting the slider to have the `stimulateTouch` option set to false when the #editor-content does exist, and have it set the option to true when the element in the body does not exist. But so far my attempted code is just making the entire slider js not function. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your code through a Javascript validator (such as this: http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) you'll find you have a syntax error on line 12.

```
stimulateTouch = false,
```

needs to be

```
stimulateTouch: false,
```

as per the other properties.

Just FYI, you may want to look into using Chrome Developer Tools or some other debugging tool to pick up small issues like this. The console will let you know if you have any syntax errors, and you can use the debugger to set breakpoints and step through your code line by line so you can find the exact spot where things start to go pear-shaped.

Comment: Omg I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the feedback! Yeah that was the issue. Thanks for linking the tool, I'll be sure to use that.